# What is the most used layout in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to add 4 buttons to the centre of the screen such that it should appear as:

```
            Button 1    Button 2
            Button 3    Button 4
```

What is the best layout method for this? Or how can I do it with different layouts.
I tried with tablelayout but the final product shifted positions in different screen sizes.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: And who will do this survey for you?

Comment: my personal suggestion is use all layout for this design. it is possible by all layouts. when you can complete this design using all layouts, i hope you will have a good knowledge about layouts

Comment: Ok. I will try with all layouts but how to ensure the buttons remain in the centre even if you use on different engines?

Comment: what is different engines?

Comment: Different engines say different devices with different screen sizes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using linear layout then android:gravity="center" ensures all the widget in the layout are in center, and if you are using relative layout then  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:layout_centerVertical="true"
keeps your widgets at center

Comment: Thanks. Let me check it.

Answer (score 0):

Linear Layout is best for this.

Answer (score 0):

I used a table layout for this sort of button arrangement.

```
    <TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/row1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <TableRow android:layout_weight="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:text="1"
            android:textSize="40sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button2"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:text="2"
            android:textSize="40sp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:layout_weight="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button3"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:text="3"
            android:textSize="40sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button4"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:text="4"
            android:textSize="40sp" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```